# how to use VBA to adjust the data selection range in a powerpoint chart

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I have a vba code that copies some data from Excel, and then pastes the data into powerpoint to create a bar chart. It does this this by pasting the data into the bar chart excel sheet. The issue I'm running into is that I the data that gets pasted to the powerpoint chart will differ in size, so I want to make sure that the powerpoint chart will include the entire contents.

Here's a sample of the code that copies data from excel to powerpoint.  The copy and pasting works fine. I just dont know how to change the data selection range

```
Thisworkbook.sheets("ws").Range("AF6:AJ6").select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown).Select
selection.Copy
With ppslide.Shapes("Chart").Chart.ChartData
.Activate
.workbook.Sheet(1).Range("A2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
.workbook.close
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`SetSourceData`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.chart.setsourcedata) method of the `Chart`.

That might look something like this:

```
With ppslide.Shapes("Chart").Chart
    With .ChartData.Workbook.Worksheets(1)
        .Range("A2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

        Dim lastRow as Long
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row

        Dim dataAddress as String
        dataAddress = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lastRow, "E")).Address(External:=True)
    End With

    .SetSourceData dataAddress
End With
```

You *might* be able to simplify using the `UsedRange` (seems to work but not thoroughly tested):

```
With ppslide.Shapes("Chart").Chart
    With .ChartData.Workbook.Worksheets(1)
        .Range("A2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

        Dim dataAddress as String
        dataAddress = .UsedRange.Address(External:=True)
    End With

    .SetSourceData dataAddress
End With
```